# Correctly using methods from additional class files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

In the efforts of trying to keep my code 'tidy' and for the sake of learning I have an application with seven class files (currently). Two extend the Activity (Main.class & Game.class).
I've been working on this 'problem' for a few days now and have seen what I thought were a lot of different solutions but have yet to get one working.

My question is: How am I able to use a method from another class without getting a NullPointerException error from the following code?

(code from Main.class)

```
public Game Ga = new Game();
```

or

```
public Game Ga;
```

Both give the same result, I have also attempted:

```
public Game Ga = ((Game)getApplicationContext());
```

My problem is that I use Eclipse and am able to begin writing `Ga.` Eclipse will then find the Game.class file and list my methods from Game.class. However, once compiled the Application crashes when trying to run the Ga. method with the Logcat: NullPointerException error.

I'm still very new to Java/Android but my debugging experience leads me to believe the Ga variable is incorrect.

edit:

Main.class

```
public class Main extends Activity {

public Game Ga;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // for testing
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    playerOne = 1;
    aiRandom();
    Ga.gameNew();
```

Game.class

```
public class Game extends Activity {

public void gameNew() {
    gameReset();
    fight();
```

Comment: post the Game code, and the error stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable name is not the issue.

Let's say your declaration is-

```
public Game Ga;
```

At this moment Ga is *null* by default. It's not been instantiated. So, if your Game class had a method named getScreenWidth that returns a floating-point value and you could access it where Ga was declared, and tried-

```
float screenWidth = Ga.getScreenWidth();
```

The above would give you NPE (*NullPointerException*) since Ga was never instantiated. But the following should work unless something else is wrong in which case you should update your question with the code in your Game class or the method you are trying to invoke and exact error logs-

```
Game Ga = new Game();
float screenWidth = Ga.getScreenWidth();
```

**UPDATE**

As you showed some code, you didn't instantiate your **Ga**. Instantiate it inside the onCreate method-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Ga = new Game();

    ...the rest of your code..
}
```

Change-

```
public class Game extends Activity
```

To-

```
public class Game
```

Comment: Thank you this works. Currently editing my files and novice question: would I need to write `Ga = new Game();` into every method it's now used in? Would I not be able to keep it 'global' ?

Comment: @TomFirth84 Your ga is already an instance variable. So, you do not need to instantiate again to use any method that Ga can invoke in the same class. You may want to read this- http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/PolymorphismInterfaces1.html

Answer (score 0):

If Game is subclass of an Activity class, and you are trying to call its methods from another activity (Main) - you are doing something wrong.
You can declare this method as static and call it like this: Game.someStaticMethod();